# magento 2 preferences - what to extend

Tags: preference

I have a question about m2 preferences (overwriting core modules). Whenever I overwrite a core module, do I have to inject all the classes the same way original class does? Also what should I extend? The class that I'm trying to overwrite or the class that the overwritten class is extending?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend the one that you're overwriting. It should contain the same parameters at a minimum because your constructor needs to call the parent constructor with the original parameters in order, i.e. `parent::__construct($context, $data);`. You can of course inject additional classes to use in your child class.